# Eclipse Toolbar: Cannot find the 'help' or 'window' text

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I just installed eclipse on a Mac (I am new to Mac).  I am trying to locate the Text in the toolbar that says 'Window' and 'Help", but cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be specific. There is no text to locate it. And if you are trying to search the window and help , it would be available at the top of mac screen.

Answer (score -1):

could it be that the last 2 menues get cut of because of the taskbar? check if you can drag behind run.

PS: would like to have this "answer" as comment since i am not sure (i dont use/have a mac)

Comment: There is no text at all. There is no 'run'. There are only icons for new, print, bug, run, package, etc.